# How to show user account update information to user using play framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

what am i doing is that when user will login and there is a section in menu `edit account` and when user click on that link to edit information new page will opened and get form to update information and after saving the updated information will save in data base  but after saving directing back to home page  and i want to show to user a message that your account has been updated

**view part** is:

[image]

user edit view part is:

[image]

**controller part** is:

when user will click on `edit user` link

```
public static Result upd(Long id) {
  Form<User> u = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
  if (u.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(editu.render(id, u));
  } else {
    u.get().update(id);
    User user = u.get();
    return ok(info.render(user));
  }
}
```

view coding part of home page `info.scala.html` is:

```
<div class="container-narrow">
  <div class="masthead">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li><a href="@routes.signin.ed(user.id)">edit User</a></li>
      <li><a href="@routes.signin.logou">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="muted">
      welcome <b>@user.getEmail()</b>
    </h3>
  </div>
<hr/>
```

**what did I try:**

**view part of home page**:

```
<div class="container-narrow">
  <div class="masthead">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li><a href="@routes.signin.ed(user.id)">edit User</a></li>
      <li><a href="@routes.signin.logou">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="muted">
       welcome <b>@user.getEmail()</b>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <hr></hr>
  <div>
    @flash.map {
      case (key, value) => {
        <p class="error">
          <span ><b>@value</b></span>
        </p>
      }
    }
  </div>
```

and **controller part** :

```
public static Result upd(Long id) {
  Form<User> u = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();

  if (u.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(editu.render(id, u));
  } else {
    u.get().update(id);
    User user = u.get();
    flash("success", Messages.get("your account has been updated"));
    return ok(info.render(user));
  }
}
```

Give me an idea to show information about the update to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `Java with Play`, but in `Scala` I use `Redirect` for such cases. So it seems to me that it may be like this :

```
....
 flash("success", Messages.get("your account has been updated"));
 return redirect ok(info.render(user));
```